# Counting letters before and after a letter

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel file of a list of sequences. How would I go about getting the number of times a letter appears before a letter in square brackets? An example of an entry is below.

```
GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCC[A]CTCCTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT
```

I'd also like to do this for the letter after the square brackets.

Edit: Apologies for the confusion. Take the example below. Id like to count how many times `A`, `C`, `G`, and `T` appears immediately before and after the letter in square brackets (for which there is only one per line). So to count the occurences of  `A[A]A`, `A[A]C`, `C[A]A`, and so on. The file is in excel, and I'm happy to use any method in excel, R or in Linux.

```
CCCACCCGCCAGGAAGCCGCTATCACTGTCCAAGTTGTCATCGGAACTCC[A]CCAGCCTGTGGACTTGGCCTGGTGCCGCCCATCCCCCTTGCGGTCCTTGC
ACCACTACCCCCTTCCCCACCATCCACCTCAGAAGCAGTCCCAGCCTGCC[A]CCCGCCAGCCCCTGCCCAGCCCTGGCTTTTTGGAAACGGGTCAGGATTGG
TTTGCTTTAAAATACTGCAACCACTCCAGGTAAATCTTCCGCTGCCTATA[A]CCCCGCCAATGAGCCTGCACATCAGGAGAGAAAGGGAAGTAACTCAAGCA
GAAATCTTCTGAAACAGTCTCCAGAAGACTGTCTCCAAATACACAGCAGA[A]CCAGCCAGTCCACAGCACTTTACCTTCTCTATTCTCAGATGGCAATTGAG
GGACTGCCCCAAGGCCCGCAGGGAGGTGGAGCTGCACTGGCGGGCCTCCC[A]GTGCCCGCACATCGTACGGATCGTGGATGTGTACGAGAATCTGTACGCAG
GGCCCAACGCCATCCTGAAACTCACTGACTTTGGCTTTGCCAAGGAAACC[A]CCAGCCACAACTCTTTGACCACTCCTTGTTATACACCGTACTATGTGGGT
TCTGCCTGGTCCGCTGGAGCTGGGCATTGAAGCCCCGCAGCTGCTCAGCC[A]CCTGCCCCGCCATCAAGAAGGCCCCACCGGCCCTGGGAAGGACACCCCTG
TTTGAAGCCCTTATGAACCAAGAAACCTTCGTTCAGGACCTCAAAATCAA[A]CCCCGCCACATGCAGCTCGCAGGCCTGCAGGAGGAAAGACAGGTTAGCAA
CTGCAGCCTACCTGTCCATGTCCCAGGGGGCCGTTGCCAACGCCAACAGC[A]CCCCGCCGCCCTATGAGCGTACCCGCCTCTCCCCACCCCGGGCCAGCTAC
ACTGGCAAACATGTTGAGGACAATGATGGAGGGGATGAGCTTGCATAGGA[A]CCTGCCGTAGGGCCACTGTCCCTGGAGAGCCAAGTGAGCCAGCGAGAAGG
CACCCTCAGAGAAGAAGAAAGGAGCTGAGGAGGAGAAGCCAAAGAGGAGG[A]GGCAGGAGAAGCAGGCAGCCTGCCCCTTCTACAACCACGAGCAGATGGGC
CCAGCCCTGTATGAGGACCCCCCAGATCAGAAAACCTCACCCAGTGGCAA[A]CCTGCCACACTCAAGATCTGCTCTTGGAATGTGGATGGGCTTCGAGCCTG
TTCCTGTGCGCCCCAACAACTCCTTTAGCTGGCCTAAAGTGAAAGGACGG[A]CCTGCCAATGAAAATAGACTTTCAGGGTCTAGCAGAAGGCAAGACCACCA
CTAACACCCGCACGAGCTGCTGGTAGATCTGAATGGCCAAGTCACTCAGC[A]CCTGCCGATACTCAGCCAGGTCAAAATTGGTGAGGCAGTGTTCATTCTGG
AGTTCTGCATCTGGAGCAAATCCTTGGCACTCCCTCATGCTGGCTATCAC[A]CCTGCCACGAATGTGCCATGGCCCAACCCTGCAGTCCATAAAGAAAACAA
CGTGCCCATGCAGCTAGTGCTCTTCCGAGAGGCTATTGAACACAGTGAGC[A]CCTGCCACGCCTATCCCCTTCCCCATCATCTCAGTGATGGGGTATGTCTA
ACAAGGACCTGGCCCTGGGGCAGCCCCTCAGCCCACCTGGTCCCTGCCTT[A]CCCAGCCAGTACTCTCCATCAGCACGGCCGAAGCCCAGCTTGTAGTCATT
```

Comment: Does each sequence contain square brackets once or more than once?

Comment: And is the letter in square brackets always 'A' or can it be C, G, T? It helps to provide a more complete example of your data.

Comment: @neilfws I've added an answer using base R.

Comment: I'm assuming from "the letter after the square brackets" that what you want to count is base frequencies at positions -1 and +1 relative to the square brackets?

Comment: There is now sufficient information in the question to answer it, if anyone wants to vote reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the original string into parts.  From the start of the string to the first [ and from the first ] to the end of the string.

```
int count = firstPart.Count(f => f == 'a');
count += secondPart.Count(f => f == 'a');
```

Comment: Question tagged 'r' so I assume they want an R solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim seq As String
    seq = "GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCC[A]CTCCTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT"
    Debug.Print CountLetter("A", seq)
End Sub

Function CountLetter(letter As String, ByVal sequence As String) As Long
    '--- assumes the letter in the brackets is the same as that being counted
    Dim allLetters() As String
    allLetters = Split("A,C,G,T", ",")

    Dim letterToDelete As Variant
    For Each letterToDelete In allLetters
        If letterToDelete <> letter Then
            sequence = Replace(sequence, letterToDelete, "")
        End If
    Next letterToDelete
    CountLetter = Len(sequence) - 1
End Function
```

Comment: Question tagged 'r' so I assume they want an R solution.

Comment: @neilfws - It is also tagged [tag:excel], which this is.

Comment: I just assumed step 1 was "get data out of Excel" :)

Comment: Yeah the question is rather unclear about what language they want

Comment: Very true, I focused on the Excel part. So this solution may be a swing and a miss.

Answer (score 1):

**New R solution (after clarification by OP)**

Let's assume the data have been read from Excel into a data.table called `los` (list of sequences) which has only one column called `sequence`. Then, the occurences can be counted as follows:

```
library(data.table)
los[, .N, by = stringr::str_extract(sequence, "[ACGT]\\[[ACGT]\\][ACGT]")]
#   stringr N
#1:   C[A]C 8
#2:   A[A]C 5
#3:   C[A]G 1
#4:   G[A]G 1
#5:   G[A]C 1
#6:   T[A]C 1
```

`str_extract()` looks for one of the letters `A`, `C`, `G`, `T` followed by `[` followed by one of the letters `A`, `C`, `G`, `T` followed by `]` followed by one of the letters `A`, `C`, `G`, `T` in column `sequence` and extracts the matching substrings. Then, `los` is grouped by the substrings and the number of occurences is counted (`.N`).

**Data**

If the Excel file is stored in CSV format then it can be read using `data.table`'s `fread()` function like this

```
los <- fread("your_file_name.csv")
```

(Perhaps, some parameters to `fread()` might need to be adjusted for the specific file.)

However, some data already are provided in the question. These can be read as character string using `fread()` as well:

```
los <- fread("sequence
CCCACCCGCCAGGAAGCCGCTATCACTGTCCAAGTTGTCATCGGAACTCC[A]CCAGCCTGTGGACTTGGCCTGGTGCCGCCCATCCCCCTTGCGGTCCTTGC
ACCACTACCCCCTTCCCCACCATCCACCTCAGAAGCAGTCCCAGCCTGCC[A]CCCGCCAGCCCCTGCCCAGCCCTGGCTTTTTGGAAACGGGTCAGGATTGG
TTTGCTTTAAAATACTGCAACCACTCCAGGTAAATCTTCCGCTGCCTATA[A]CCCCGCCAATGAGCCTGCACATCAGGAGAGAAAGGGAAGTAACTCAAGCA
GAAATCTTCTGAAACAGTCTCCAGAAGACTGTCTCCAAATACACAGCAGA[A]CCAGCCAGTCCACAGCACTTTACCTTCTCTATTCTCAGATGGCAATTGAG
GGACTGCCCCAAGGCCCGCAGGGAGGTGGAGCTGCACTGGCGGGCCTCCC[A]GTGCCCGCACATCGTACGGATCGTGGATGTGTACGAGAATCTGTACGCAG
GGCCCAACGCCATCCTGAAACTCACTGACTTTGGCTTTGCCAAGGAAACC[A]CCAGCCACAACTCTTTGACCACTCCTTGTTATACACCGTACTATGTGGGT
TCTGCCTGGTCCGCTGGAGCTGGGCATTGAAGCCCCGCAGCTGCTCAGCC[A]CCTGCCCCGCCATCAAGAAGGCCCCACCGGCCCTGGGAAGGACACCCCTG
TTTGAAGCCCTTATGAACCAAGAAACCTTCGTTCAGGACCTCAAAATCAA[A]CCCCGCCACATGCAGCTCGCAGGCCTGCAGGAGGAAAGACAGGTTAGCAA
CTGCAGCCTACCTGTCCATGTCCCAGGGGGCCGTTGCCAACGCCAACAGC[A]CCCCGCCGCCCTATGAGCGTACCCGCCTCTCCCCACCCCGGGCCAGCTAC
ACTGGCAAACATGTTGAGGACAATGATGGAGGGGATGAGCTTGCATAGGA[A]CCTGCCGTAGGGCCACTGTCCCTGGAGAGCCAAGTGAGCCAGCGAGAAGG
CACCCTCAGAGAAGAAGAAAGGAGCTGAGGAGGAGAAGCCAAAGAGGAGG[A]GGCAGGAGAAGCAGGCAGCCTGCCCCTTCTACAACCACGAGCAGATGGGC
CCAGCCCTGTATGAGGACCCCCCAGATCAGAAAACCTCACCCAGTGGCAA[A]CCTGCCACACTCAAGATCTGCTCTTGGAATGTGGATGGGCTTCGAGCCTG
TTCCTGTGCGCCCCAACAACTCCTTTAGCTGGCCTAAAGTGAAAGGACGG[A]CCTGCCAATGAAAATAGACTTTCAGGGTCTAGCAGAAGGCAAGACCACCA
CTAACACCCGCACGAGCTGCTGGTAGATCTGAATGGCCAAGTCACTCAGC[A]CCTGCCGATACTCAGCCAGGTCAAAATTGGTGAGGCAGTGTTCATTCTGG
AGTTCTGCATCTGGAGCAAATCCTTGGCACTCCCTCATGCTGGCTATCAC[A]CCTGCCACGAATGTGCCATGGCCCAACCCTGCAGTCCATAAAGAAAACAA
CGTGCCCATGCAGCTAGTGCTCTTCCGAGAGGCTATTGAACACAGTGAGC[A]CCTGCCACGCCTATCCCCTTCCCCATCATCTCAGTGATGGGGTATGTCTA
ACAAGGACCTGGCCCTGGGGCAGCCCCTCAGCCCACCTGGTCCCTGCCTT[A]CCCAGCCAGTACTCTCCATCAGCACGGCCGAAGCCCAGCTTGTAGTCATT")
```

---

**Old solution (before clarification by OP) - left here for reference**

This is a solution in base R with help of the `stringr` package which will work with a "list" of sequences (a data.frame), any single letter enclosed in square brackets, and arbitrary lengths of the sequences. It assumes that the data already have been read from file into a data.frame which is named `los` here.

```
# create data: data frame with two sequences
los <- data.frame(
  sequence = c("GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCC[A]CTCCTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT",
               "GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCCACT[C]CTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT")) 

# split sequences in three parts
mat <- stringr::str_split_fixed(los$sequence, "[\\[\\]]", n = 3)
los$letter <- mat[, 2]
los$n_before <- stringr::str_count(mat[, 1], mat[, 2])
los$n_after <- stringr::str_count(mat[, 3], mat[, 2])
print(los)
#                                                     sequence letter n_before n_after
#1 GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCC[A]CTCCTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT      A        3       4
#2 GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCCACT[C]CTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT      C        9       9
```

Note this code works best if there is exactly one pair of square brackets in each sequence. Any additional brackets will be ignored.

It will also work if there is more than just one letter enclosed in brackets, e.g., `[GT]`.

I'm confessing that I'm addicted to Hadley Wickham's `stringr` package because I have difficulties to remember the inconsistently named base R functions for string maninpulation like `strsplit`, `grepl`, `sub`, `match`, `gregexpr`, etc. To understand what I mean please have a look at the *Usage* and *See Also* sections of `?grep` and compare to [stringr](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = "GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCC[A]CTCCTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT"

#COUNT 'A'
sapply(unlist(strsplit(x,"\\[[A-z]\\]")), function(a) length(unlist(gregexpr("A", a))))
#  GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCC CTCCTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT 
#                            3                             4 

#COUNT 'G'
sapply(unlist(strsplit(x,"\\[[A-z]\\]")), function(a) length(unlist(gregexpr("G", a))))
#  GTCCTGGTTGTAGCTGAAGCTCTTCCC CTCCTCCCGATCACTGGGACGTCCTATGT 
#                            7                             6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that R packages for bioinformatics, such as [seqinr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqinr/index.html) or [Biostrings](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html), would be a good starting point. However, here's a "roll your own" solution.

First step: get your data from Excel into R. I will assume that file `mydata.xlsx` contains one sheet with a column of sequence and no header. You need to adapt this for your file and sheet format.

```
library(readxl)
sequences <- read_excel("mydata.xlsx", col_names = FALSE)
colnames(sequences) <- "sequence"
```

Now you need a function to extract the base in square brackets and the bases at -1 and +1. This function uses the `stringr` package to extract bases using regular expressions.

```
get_bases <- function(seq) {
  require(stringr)
  require(magrittr)
  subseqs <- str_match(seq, "^([ACGT]+)\\[([ACGT])\\]([ACGT]+)$")
  bases <- list(
    before = subseqs[, 2] %>% str_sub(-1, -1),
    base   = subseqs[, 3],
    after  = subseqs[, 4] %>% str_sub(1, 1)
  )
  return(bases)
}
```

Now you can pass the column of sequences to the function to generate a list of lists, which can be converted to a data frame.

```
library(purrr)
sequences_df <- lapply(sequences, get_bases) %>% 
  map_df(as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

head(sequences_df, 3)

  before base after
1      C    A     C
2      C    A     C
3      A    A     C
```

The last step is to use functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr` to count up the bases.

```
library(tidyr)
sequences_df %>% 
  gather(position, letter, -base) %>% 
  group_by(base, position, letter) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  spread(position, n) %>% 
  select(base, letter, before, after)
```

Result using your 17 example sequences. I would use better names than I did if I were you: `base` = the base in square brackets, `letter` = the base being counted, `before` = count at -1, `after` = count at +1.

```
   base letter before after
* <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>
1     A      A      5    NA
2     A      C      9    15
3     A      G      2     2
4     A      T      1    NA
```